# Prevent URL from redirecting

Tags: html, url, redirect, hyperlink, download

This is the same question that has been asked elsewhere on the site but at the moment it's in the C# and .Net categories and so are the answers whereas i need to know how to do it in html.

So i'm trying to download the file at url `http://example.com/example.docx` and the url s being redirected to `http://example.com/example.docx?` so internet explorer doesn't recognize it although Google chrome does oddly. So i would like to know is there any way to avoid this happening by altering my html code?

Html Code is pretty standard...

```
<p><a href="http://example.com/example.docx">Link Text></a></p>
```

Finally if you type in http://example.com/example.docx manually it works

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried linking to it with the `?` already added?  No redirect then, and it should work as if it wasn't there.

Comment: no that doesn't work thanks for trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirection is happening on the server side - it is doing the redirection at the end URL.

There is nothing you can do to your markup to change this.

Comment: thanks i feared this was the problem but the site is taking ages to solve it and more irritatingly if you manually type http://example.com/example.docx then it works

Comment: @user1205406 - If you type it manually and it works, then there is no reason for it not to work from the page (unless they look at the `HTTP_REFERER` header - something that can't be controlled from HTML only).

Comment: its totally illogical and very annoying